# Codeigniter routes not working sometimes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a little question. I am using Codeigniter 2.1.0 and I have the following code in my routes.php.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "photo";
$route['404_override'] = 'error';

$route['photo/:num'] = 'photo/index/$1';
$route['people/:num'] = 'people/index/$1';
```

The weird thing is, sometimes when I go to http://www.myurl.com/photo/1 it works and othertimes it redirects me to my error page.

Anyone maby has any idea what is wrong with my routes ?

Already thanks in advance!

Bob

Comment: Have you tried enclosing `(:num)` in parenthesis? It may be required if you are using `$1` in your route.

Comment: Used to have this but because I also had the error when I had (:num) I removed the parenthesis.

Comment: You have .htaccess file working to remove the `index.php` from your URLs, right? If so, you don't need a custom route. photo/1 automatically goes to photo/index/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct

```
$route['photo/(:num)'] = 'photo/index/$1';
$route['people/(:num)'] = 'people/index/$1';
```

you have to write this route

```
$route['photo/(:num)'] = 'photo/$1';
$route['people/(:num)'] = 'people/$1';
```

in that way only number are permitted.

index is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case, but you might want to put parentheses around the wildcards:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "photo";
$route['404_override'] = 'error';

$route['photo/(:num)'] = 'photo/index/$1';
$route['people/(:num)'] = 'people/index/$1';
```

Comment: Used to have this but because I also had the error when I had (:num) I removed the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

when you use route in Codeigniter, don't forget .httacess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and remove index.php in the config.php file `$config['index_page'] = '';`