# Why aren't my routes working in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have already read a bunch of the articles on stackoverflow about this topic, such as:

[CodeIgniter: SEO friendly URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362460/codeigniter-seo-friendly-urls)

[Codeigniter routes not working sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450614/codeigniter-routes-not-working-sometimes)

And I swear I have set up everything correctly, but after I put the route in and save my app, and attempt to go to the new URL, or even the old one, they both give me a 404 error.

I have an extension that currently looks like this:

**search/map_view/county**

that I want to look like this:

**map/county**

I wrote the following reroute in the routes.php file, which gives me the 404 error:

```
$route['search/map_view/(:any)'] = 'map/$1';
```

And just in case I was doing it backwards, I also tried it like this:

```
$route['map/(:any)'] = 'search/map_view/$1';
```

That didn't do anything, so I've deduced i did that incorrectly. A thing of note is that I do have apache's mod_rewrite changing my url's to drop the index.php from it. Don't know how that's helpful, but I've noticed it a lot in the other posts.

Am I supposed to change something somewhere else for this? I'm assuming that if I type in the previous address, I should get automatically rerouted to the new one? Or if I type in the new address, it should work automatically? I don't know, it's getting really annoying...

Anyhow, I have a lot of questions about this stuff, but I'm going to start  here and then see if I can find the rest of the answers here after I fix this one.

***EDIT*** - I've been asked to include more info. Here it is.

Here's the .htaccess content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Currently I don't have any custom routes defined in the routes.php file, just because I can't get it to work correctly.

The current controller is "Search", with the method "map_view" being passed a variable "county". So the url would be

```
http://www.base_url.com/search/map_view/county
```

I want to change this to

```
http://www.base_url.com/map/county
```

Everything else I've previously written still applies. Thanks again!

Comment: Your route here needs to match an actual route.

Answer (score 2):

You want your url looks like **map/country** .

In your `routes.php`

```
$route['map/(:any)'] = 'search/map_view/$1';
$route['map'] = 'search/map_view';
```

And be sure your controller name is `Search.php`.Also class name is `Search` that extends `CI_Controller` and method name `map_view()` *(must be public function)*

Look [**CI Controller Guide**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) for detailed information

Comment: Thanks for your response - I tried this - and I'm still getting a 404 error. The current controller is called "Search", and it definitely extends CI_Controller. It works great now, but I"m trying to shorten up my URL's for SEO purposes. The method it accesses currently is called "map_view". If I create this route and I want it to change "search/map_view/county" to be "map/county", do I need to have a new controller called "Map"? Maybe I just don't understand very clearly how this routing thing works - it just seems to me like a way to make the URL's not quite so ugly and more accessible...

Comment: edit you main post and include your `.htaccess`, `route.php` and `Search controller`

Comment: I added the requested information. And I have read the user_guide like 1000 times, searched google, and looked for as many examples of how this works. I try to do my homework, but I swear I'm doing exactly what everything says should work, and I keep getting the 404. I haven't tried creating a new controller with the name of the intended route, but to me, that seems like it would defeat the purpose of the routes...

Comment: I am kind of having the same problem. Its working in one project and not in another. Did you find the solution @Jonathan